# LIVEMESSAGING Using " FaceBook API " in Silverlight Application

Tags: .net, silverlight, facebook

I'm using a Silverlight Application and want to use `LIVEMESSAGE` class for Instant Messaging through FaceBook API. Can any body tell me how to use this `LIVEMESSAGE` for Messaging by using an Example?

Thanxs In Advance,

Ravi Joshi

Answer (score 0):

I found this example code here:  http://blog.thaichaiguy.com/406/facebook-livemessages-from-experience/, hope it helps.